# Firmware disassembler for c-sky processor (ck803s)

Tags: reverse-engineering

подскажите, почему objdump не корректно разбирает прошивку процессора C-SKY (ck803s)? что такое .long: между строк, неизвестные инструкции? или я неправильно устанавливаю параметры objdump? вот мои: ./objdump -D -b binary -m csky:cs803 -EL firmware.bin
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из офф. источников используется процессор CK803S

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это как работает загрузчик

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

происходит запуск прошивки с указаного адреса по смещению 0x04, смотрим дамп слитый с флешки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вывод objdump

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, так как на [ru.so] вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [so] на английском.

Comment: По идее это секция данных (.data про это говорит). Если это так, то тут вообще нет кода, нет смысла ее пытаться дизассемблировать.

Comment: на .data можно не обращать внимание, как objdump может определять в бинарном файле где код, а где данные ? в дампе нет 32 битных инструкций, хотя в исходниках binutils вроде как поддерживаюся

Comment: В любом случае, если дизассемблерный листинг перемежается инструкциями данных - либо это не код, либо архитектура/процессор неправильно указаны, либо дизассемблер не все команды знает в этой архитектуре. Ну вот последный листинг интуитивно более адекватно выглядит, но есть предположение, что bf на второй строке всегда делает переход на `...00ca`, и подряд ниже этой команды не нужно дизассемблировать (это предположение, я не знаю эту архитектуру, но по операнду похоже, что это какой-то переход, хотя могу и ошибиться). Я бы попробовал через IDA прогнать.

Comment: у меня была мысль написать свой дизассемблер, но тогда первым идет инструкция 0xC001112C, по описанию это 32 битная инструкция, на это указывают биты 30 и 31, но такую инструкцию я не нашел в документации

Comment: IDA не поддерживает этот процессор, авторы сообщили о низком приоритете его добавить, у меня тоже возникает мысль что производитель не правильно указал ядро, скорее всего сознательно

Comment: insolor вторая строка это мусор именно по адресу 0x03000004 находится 0x03001000, как и описано в запуске загрузчика

Comment: не знаю как добавить картинку в комментарии, но по описанию команд включенные биты 31 и 30 указывают на 32 битную инструкцию, все остальное это 16 битные инструкции

Comment: можно ли указать objdump что данные и инструкции 32 битные ? она даже данные выделяет как 16 битные little-endian

Comment: Пишите обращение через @ник, так я буду получать оповещения о комментариях. В комменты нельзя добавлять картинки, можно кидать в поле ответа снизу (но сам ответ не публиковать), потом оттуда копировать сслыку в комментарий. По поводу objdump не знаю, может там просто не полный набор команд реализован. Чтобы не писать с нуля дизассемблер, можно попробовать radare2 или rizin (rizin - форк radare2), там теоретически можно добавить свои дизассемблерные плагины. Если rizin, то теоретически можно свой плагин к rizin использовать с cutter (их GUI оболочка для дизассемблера).

Comment: @insolor два разных устройства, а начало прошивки одинаковы, похоже есть некий заголовок: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Xow.jpg

Comment: у меня все получилось и даже подправил прошивку, там действительно процессор c-cky